# I can't figure out how to extract variables from api

Tags: c#, uwp

I have tried to fix this problem with my project for a while the getjokes returns null values and even though I don't have any errors. I am trying to make a app where there is just a simple joke shown. The api link is here [APIlink](https://sv443.net/jokeapi/category/Any).

This is the first time I have ever put anything on here so I'm probably doing it wrong but if anyone can help I will appreciate it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JokeApp.Classes
{
    public class Main
    {
        [JsonProperty("category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("setup")]
        public string Setup { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("delivery")]
        public string Delivery { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class catagories
    {
        [JsonProperty("categories")]
        public List<String> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class main
    {
        [JsonProperty("Main")]
        public Main Main { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("categories")]
        public string catogories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace JokeApp.Classes
{
    class CardWrapper
    {
        public static async Task<Main> Getjokes()
        {
            Uri request = new Uri(@"https://sv443.net/jokeapi/category/any");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User_Agent" ,"JokeApp");
            HttpResponseMessage respons = await client.GetAsync(request);

            if (respons.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
            {
                MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Cant find jokes!!");
                await md.ShowAsync();
            }

            respons.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            main mc = await respons.Content.ReadAsAsync<main>();

            return mc.Main;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

using JokeApp.Classes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using static JokeApp.Classes.Main;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409
namespace JokeApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Getjokes();
        }

        private Main _joke = new Main();

        public Main Jokes
        {
            get { return _joke; }
            set { _joke = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private async void Getjokes()
        {
           Jokes  = await CardWrapper.Getjokes();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try getting the full response content (print, log or debug) and see.

Comment: Thanks for using my API! You can refer to the C# example [listed here on the documentation](https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2#examples) if you didn't solve the issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

The response from sv443 looks like it would deserialize to an object of class Main, not of class main. So you probably want:

> Main mc = await respons.Content.ReadAsAsync();

instead of

> main mc = await respons.Content.ReadAsAsync();

In general, it's a bad idea to have two class definitions that differ only in capitalization, precisely because this type of problem can occur.

If that's not it, try logging your `respons.Content` as a `string` and see what's actually in there.

Comment: Can you say *why* it should be `main` instead of `Main`?